# How to integrate React js along with Laravel 8?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, web

I am new for Laravel React. I want to integrate React js along with laravel as a API Backend. I have a very good knowledge regarding how to work with Laravel. But I cannot manage React redirection along with Laravel routes and all. How and where can I get my solution?

Comment: You need to redirect all the routes beside the apis (let's say the api routes prefixes with `/_api/`) to `*`. This way, React will handle the routes.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is on the official documentation of Laravel : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#using-react

```
composer require laravel/ui

// Generate basic scaffolding...
php artisan ui react

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui react --auth
```